# Proof of an inequality by induction

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, telescopic-series

Prove using induction that

$$\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{n^2} \le 2-\frac{1}{n}$$

for all positive whole numbers $n$.

I began by showing that it is true for $n=1$

I then assumed that it is true for $n=p$
$$\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{p^2} = \sum_{k=1}^p \frac{1}{k^2} \le 2-\frac{1}{p}$$

I now want to show that it is true for $n=p+1$

$$\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{p^2} + \frac{1}{(p+1)^2}= \sum_{k=1}^{p+1} \frac{1}{k^2} $$

If I add $\frac{1}{(p+1)^2}$ to $\sum_{k=1}^{p} \frac{1}{k^2}$, I will then get

$$\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{p^2} + \frac{1}{(p+1)^2} \le 2-\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{(p+1)^2}$$

If this is true then 
$$2-\frac{1}{(p+1)}=2-\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{(p+1)^2}$$
or
$$-\frac{1}{(p+1)}=-\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{(p+1)^2}$$
$$0= \frac{1}{(p+1)} -\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{(p+1)^2}$$
$$0= \frac{p(p+1)}{p(p+1)^2} -\frac{(p+1)^2}{p(p+1)^2} + \frac{p}{p(p+1)^2}$$
$$0= \frac{p(p+1)}{p(p+1)^2} -\frac{(p+1)^2}{p(p+1)^2} + \frac{p}{p(p+1)^2}$$
$$0= \frac{p(p+1)-(p+1)^2 + p}{p(p+1)^2}$$
$$0= \frac{(p^2 + p) - (p^2 + 2p + 1) + p}{p(p+1)^2}$$
$$0= \frac{-1}{p(p+1)^2}$$
This is invalid. I am not sure where I have made a mistake but I think it is
$$2-\frac{1}{(p+1)}=2-\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{(p+1)^2}$$
It then must be that
$$-\frac{1}{(p+1)} < -\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{(p+1)^2}$$
$$0 \le \frac{1}{(p+1)} - \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{(p+1)^2}$$
$$ 0< \frac{-1}{p(p+1)^2}$$
which is true for all positive whole numbers $p$.
I am pretty sure it is proved now but I would be happy if someone can confirm this.

Comment: No need for equality as a special case. Just use $\le$ instead of $<$.

Comment: How could $\frac{-1}{p(p+1)^2}$ be a positive? The last line

Comment: You wrote: "If this is true then 
$$2-\frac{1}{(p+1)}=2-\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{(p+1)^2}\text{"}$$ But what you really need is $$2-\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{(p+1)^2} \leq 2-\frac{1}{(p+1)}$$

Comment: @Bungo You can write $\frac{1}{p+1}$. You don't need the parentheses $\frac{1}{(p+1)}$.

Comment: @Ameryr Ah I see the mistake now

Comment: @Bungo Indeed, Thank you!

Comment: @user236182 I lazily copy/pasted from the OP's question :-)

Comment: Another one: [Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} \le 2 - \frac{1}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638418/show-that-sum-i-1n-frac1i2-le-2-frac1n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following induction a bit of better.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}=1+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k^2}<1+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=1+\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)=1+1-\frac{1}{n}=2-\frac{1}{n}.$$

Comment: Pure (math) poetry!

Comment: It's a nice proof, but where's the induction?

Comment: @Bungo We can understand what is it $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(...)$  by induction.

Answer (score 2):

It can be much simpler.

You have equality for $n = 1$.

Adding a new $n+1$ term adds $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ to LHS and $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ to the RHS. Guess which one is smaller for all $n>1$?!

Comment: That is a lot easier. Thanks!